# Aptana 3 + Xdebug issues

Tags: php, xdebug, aptana3

I'm trying to get Aptana 3 to work with Xdebug and Firefox on Ubuntu 10.04.  I have no problems setting this up with PhpStorm, so I'm blaming Aptana at the moment.

I'm at a loss as to what is wrong... if I run the page as a script, it works fine and I can step through the code, though that option has since mysteriously disappeared.

If I select Run as PHP Server, the page appears in FF but the debugger doesn't run.  The following error message appears in the Aptana log:

```
ENTRY org.eclipse.debug.core 4 125 2013-01-02 13:54:40.040
!MESSAGE Error logged from Debug Core: 
!STACK 0
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getBufIfOpen(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.OutputStreamMonitor.read(OutputStreamMonitor.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.OutputStreamMonitor.access$1(OutputStreamMonitor.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.OutputStreamMonitor$1.run(OutputStreamMonitor.java:207)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

If I try to launch via the Run configuration it pops up a FF window that goes to Aptana's homepage and a progress bar dialog box that eventually just times out.

The Aptana plugin icon on the lower right is lit up, so I don't think that that's the issue.  There's no message in the console or browser output.  The Aptana log file is blank.

You can find pics of the [Aptana Run config here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/91785831@N02/8338580477/in/photostream), and [FF+progress bar here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/91785831@N02/8339638582/in/photostream/).

This is massively annoying... debugging is pretty basic, you'd think this would either be well documented (I can't find anything about it) or simple to set up (hah! obviously not).  Grrrrr...

Comment: Could easily be an Xdebug issues too - have you installed the latest version?